Using terminal command or script to turn on/off time sensitive notifications in Focus preferences
I am using macOS Monterey. I wanted to know if there is a Terminal command or a script that I can run to turn ON/OFF time sensitive notifications in Focus preferences.
I am new to scripting and I came to know that using the command open "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.notifications?Focus" I can open the Focus preferences.
I don't know if there is any command to click on options and toggle the checkbox for allowing time-sensitive notifications.

